# How to modify cloned field form value and id inside table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 fields in my form that I want to clone using jQuery, but the selecting html table structure got me confused on how to change the id and the value of my form field and also the label text. Here's the form field structure

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr id="attribute-name">
      <td class="label"><label for="listing_qty">quantity</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_qty" name="field_name[]" value="quantity" class="required-entry disabled attribute-name input-text" readonly="1" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="attribute-custom">
      <td class="label"></td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_custom_field" name="custom_field[]" value="" placeholder="Custom Attribute Field" type="text" class=" input-text">
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to clone the entire element and then update the id's, values, and text in the cloned element before inserting.

```js
function appendClonedFormInput(el,
  newId,
  newInputId,
  newLabelText,
  newName,
  newValue) {
  // Clone and update id
  var $cloned = $(el)
    .clone()
    .attr('id', newId);
  // Update label
  $cloned.find('label')
    .attr('for', newInputId)
    .text(newLabelText);
  // Update input
  $cloned.find('input')
    .attr('id', newInputId)
    .attr('name', newName)
    .val(newValue);
  return $cloned.insertAfter(
    $('input').last().parents('tr'));
}


appendClonedFormInput('#attribute-name',
  'new-attribute-id',
  'new-inp-id',
  'New Label',
  'new_field',
  'new value');


appendClonedFormInput('#attribute-custom',
  'new-custom-id',
  'new-custom-inp-id',
  'New Custom',
  'new_custom',
  'new custom value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="attribute-name">
      <td class="label">
        <label for="listing_qty">quantity</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_qty" name="field_name[]" value="quantity" class="required-entry disabled attribute-name input-text" readonly="1" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="attribute-custom">
      <td class="label"></td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_custom_field" name="custom_field[]" value="" placeholder="Custom Attribute Field" type="text" class=" input-text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but what happen when my row is inside the <tbody> without id, how to append it using the class/id from the last form field

Comment: I updated cloning method to insert after the last `<tr>` containing an input element.

`$cloned.insertAfter($('input').last().parents('tr'));`

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the HTML element using `.clone()` jquery function and on the cloned HTML element perform all the jquery operation as we can perform on normal jquery selector.

Please check below working snippet. In snippet I have changed the label name and ids.

```js
$(function(){
  var _counter = 1;
  $("#cloned_html").on("click",function(){
    var $button = $('#attribute-name').clone().prop("id","attribute-name-"+_counter);
    $button.find('#listing_qty').prop("id","listing_qty_"+_counter).val("quantity-"+_counter);
    
    $button.find("label").html("Quantity-"+_counter);
    var selector = '#attribute-name'
    if(_counter>1){
      selector = '#attribute-name-'+(_counter-1)
    }
    $($button).insertAfter(selector);  
    _counter++;
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr id="attribute-name">
      <td class="label"><label for="listing_qty">quantity</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_qty" name="field_name[]" value="quantity" class="required-entry disabled attribute-name input-text" readonly="1" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="attribute-custom">
      <td class="label"></td>
      <td class="value">
        <input id="listing_custom_field" name="custom_field[]" value="" placeholder="Custom Attribute Field" type="text" class=" input-text">
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button id="cloned_html">Clone</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but what happen when my row is inside the <tbody> without id, how to append it using the class/id from the last form field

Comment: Not getting you. Can you please share your HTML. And can you please also share your expected output.

Comment: i've edit my code example in my question, the tbody and table dont can't have any id, so how can i append if they dont have any id?

Comment: Please check my updated snippet. You can append cloned tr even if tbody or table don't have ids.

Comment: thanks for your answer :D, its close to what i want, the custum attribut field need to be cloned too

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the final render from the template. Another important part of your feature would be assign an unique number to compose ids and names.

I would suggest you to implement a solution like https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Put the template inside a script node with an Id then copy it's content and replace {} occurrences as you need.